# Mockito:: Null pointer exception for MockMVC

Tags: mockito, spring-mvc-test, mockmvc

I am having project in spring-mvc. I wrote a test case in mockito, Below is the code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@Configurable
public class ABCControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    CustomerController instance;

    @Mock
    Service paymentService;

    @Mock
    OfferService offerService;

    @Mock
    CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Mock
    Category category;

    @Mock
    RuleService ruleService ;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    public PaymentCustomerControllerTest() {
    }

   @Before
    public void setup() {

        // this must be called for the @Mock annotations above to be processed
        // and for the mock service to be injected into the controller under
        // test.
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(instance).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetNewCashback() throws Exception {
        int a= 100; 
        int b=200;
      //  System.out.print(mockMvc);
       try{
           mockMvc.perform(
                get("repo/getTotalSum?Id=306187C35A5C98A1B01E3DCDE8BAC1DA&visitId=306187C35A5C98A1B01E3DCDE8BAC1DA&mobileStatus=0"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
       }catch(Exception ex){
           System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
       }
       a = 100;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetNewCashback() throws Exception {

        ResultDTO result = instance.getTotalSum(Id, visitId, mobileStatus);
        assertEquals(result, expResult);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
   }

}
```

and this is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ssww.cust</groupId>
    <artifactId>cust</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Settlement</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>

        <spring.core.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.core.version>
        <spring.security.core.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.security.core.version>
        <spring.data.jpa.version>1.1.0.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>

        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.21</mysql.connector.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>

        <querydsl.version>2.7.0</querydsl.version>

        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>

        <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.6.12</aspectj.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <javax.servlet-api.version>2.5</javax.servlet-api.version>
        <javax.jstl-taglibs.version>1.1.2</javax.jstl-taglibs.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.3</jackson.version>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <mockito.version>1.8.5</mockito.version>
        <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>

        <!-- Plugins -->
        <maven.copy.plugin.version>0.2.3</maven.copy.plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>2.3.2</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.apt.plugin.version>1.0</maven.apt.plugin.version>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <!-- javamelody-core >
        <dependency>
                <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
                <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.49.0</version>
        </dependency-->
        <!-- itext, option to add PDF export -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>bctsp-jdk14</artifactId>
                    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-impl-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Alpha3</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- A seamless aspect-oriented extension to the Java programming language -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cglib is a powerful, high performance and quality Code Generation
        Library, It is used to extend JAVA classes and implements interfaces at runtime. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>${cglib.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- The JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL) encapsulates, as
        simple tags, core functionality common to many JSP applications. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.jstl-taglibs.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.jstl-taglibs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Data Mapper package is a high-performance data binding package built
        on Jackson JSON processor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson is a high-performance JSON processor (parser, generator) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logger -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- The Simple Logging Facade for Java or (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade
        or abstraction for various logging frameworks, e.g. java.util.logging, log4j
        and logback, allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging framework
        at deployment time. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Database pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate and JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- QueryDSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Javax Servlet. This needs to be included for runtime only! -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modeshape</groupId>
            <artifactId>modeshape-sequencer-msoffice</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
            <version>R8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
            <version>R8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mixpanel</groupId>
            <artifactId>mixpanel-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.50</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>settlement</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.2.v20100523</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.7.201204190339</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <addContextWarDependencies>true</addContextWarDependencies>
                    </configuration>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <ajpPort>8391</ajpPort>
                        <port>8392</port>
                        <addContextWarDependencies>true</addContextWarDependencies>
                    </configuration>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <repositories>

        <!-- For main Spring releases -->
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework.maven.release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <!--
                <repository>
                    <id>jboss</id>
                    <name>JBoss repository</name>
                    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
                </repository>
        -->

    </repositories>

</project>
```

But on building the project , i am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ABCControllerTest.testGetNewCashback(ABCControllerTest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.surefire.battery.AbstractBattery.executeTestMethod(AbstractBattery.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.surefire.battery.AbstractBattery.executeTestMethods(AbstractBattery.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.surefire.battery.AbstractBattery.execute(AbstractBattery.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.surefire.battery.JUnitBattery.execute(JUnitBattery.java:224)
    at org.codehaus.surefire.Surefire.executeBattery(Surefire.java:204)
    at org.codehaus.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:153)
    at org.codehaus.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at the value of mock is getting null, so getting null pointer exception. I googled out, changed spring version to 4.0.0Release, still same.
```

Any idea? Thanks.

After changing to standalone:i am getting java.lang.Exception: mvc is having null value.this is my code

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PaymentCustomerControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;



   @Before
    public void setUp() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            CustomerController instance = new CustomerController();

            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(instance).build();
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetNewCashback() throws Exception {
       if(mockMvc==null){
            throw new Exception("mvc is having null value");
        }
           mockMvc.perform(
                get("info/getInfo?Id=306&visitId=30618&mobileStatus=0"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Mockito for your tests, you must use `MockitoJUnitRunner` not `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`

Comment: Thanks, but i am getting java.lang.Exception: mvc is having null value.

Comment: You can not use spring related annotations/configuration when running the test case with MockitoJunitRunner. `@ContextConfiguration, MockMvc and @WebAppConfiguration should not be used in your test case.` See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068740/spring-controller-testing-with-mockito

Comment: MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) is the equivalent if you want to use a different runner